# Как избавится от ошибки Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ','?

Tags: phpmailer

вот сам код:

```
<?php
    require 'PHPMailer-master/class.phpmailer.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail -> isSMTP();
    $mail -> Host = 'smtp.mail.ru';
    $mail -> SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail -> Username = 'Gonsallos';
    $mail -> Password = 'пароль';
    $mail -> SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail -> Port ='465';
    $mail -> CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $mail -> From = 'Gonsallos@mail.ru';
    $mail -> FromName = 'Андрей';
    $mail -> AddAddress = ('Dima_kisill@meta.ua', 'Дмитрию');
    $mail -> isHTML(true);
    $mail -> Subject = 'Тема сообщения!';
    $mail -> Body = 'Привет, мир!<p>Это строка<b>HTML кода</b></p>';
    $mail -> AltBody = 'Это альтернативное сообщение!';
    //$mail -> SMTPDebug =1; Выводим ошибку!

    if($mail -> send()){
        echo "Письмо отправлено!";
    }else{
        echo "Письмо не может быть отправлено. ";
        echo "Ошибка".$mail -> ErrorInfo;
    }   
?>
```

На строке: `$mail -> AddAddress = ('Dima_kisill@meta.ua', 'Дмитрию');`
выдает такую ошибку:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in...

Знаю что синтаксическая ошибка, но не пойму что не так.

Comment: а как насчет закрытия `$mail -> Body = 'Привет, мир!`? Я имею ввиду `$mail -> Body = 'Привет, мир!'`

Comment: Кажется я плохо написал сюда код, не все показывает...
Но дело даже не в этом сама суть, ошибка на строке: 
$mail -> AddAddress = ('Dima_kisill@meta.ua', 'Дмитрию');
вот ошибка:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in...

Comment: А что, по-вашему, такое  `('asd', 'qweq')` в терминах PHP? Подскажу, это не массив!

Comment: я не пойму, прошу вашей помощи...

Answer (score 1):

`AddAddress` - это не *переменная*, а ***метод***. Вызывать надо так:

```
$mail->AddAddress('Dima_kisill@meta.ua', 'Дмитрию');
```

Comment: Сделал как вы написали, но теперь пишет такое:

Fatal error: Class 'SMTP' not found in...

Comment: @Дмитрий http://stackoverflow.com/a/23764509/5611260

Comment: А вот теперь выводит такую ошибку:
Extension missing: openssl

Comment: @Дмитрий Вы принципиально не пользуетесь поисковыми системами? Раскомментируйте в `php.ini` строку вида `extension=php_openssl.dll`.

Comment: Все равно не работает...(
уже везде облазил, не могу понять...

Comment: @Дмитрий После изменения `php.ini` нужно перезапустить web-сервер.

Comment: это я знаю, делал, все равно пишет:
Extension missing: openssl

Comment: может проблемка уже в сервере?